# Did Harry or Ron ever master nonverbal spells? Were nonverbal spells used by the trio during Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

We see that Hermione had learnt the art of nonverbal spells during their sixth year, while Harry and Ron were struggling with it. Is there any evidence that either of them got the hang of nonverbal spells and used them in DH?

Also, do we see any instance where Hermione uses nonverbal spells in *Deathly Hallows*, in tricky situations?

Comment: hermione imperius people a few times nonverbally

Comment: @Himarm really? Can you give an example? I know Harry used it and McGonagall did but did Hermione? I'm quite curious.

Comment: @Pryftan i believe she uses it on a goblin at the bank, and maybe 1 more time in the same scene on a death eater.

Comment: @Himarm No. That's Harry invisibly. And the Death Eater was Travers.

Comment: @Pryftan your right i had hermione in my head good catch

Comment: I usually am right - when I have the idea I am. Not always though and I can accept when I'm not quite easily. But I can't deny I would have found it somewhat enjoyable (not sure that's the right word but it'll do) if I truly had missed Hermione using an Unforgivable Curse at all let alone non-verbally. Though I would have been also baffled.

Comment: Ron does not say anything when he casts that slug curse on Malfoy in 2nd year. Granted it backfired, but that was because of the wand

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Hermione did use nonverbal spells during Deathly Hallows.**

Hermione is explicitly shown to use a non-verbal spell at least once.

> “Little more than a minute later, there was a tiny pop and a little Ministry witch with flyaway, grey hair Apparated feet from them, blinking a little in the sudden brightness; the sun had just come out from behind a cloud. She barely had time to enjoy the unexpected warmth, however, before Hermione’s silent Stunning Spell hit her in the chest and she toppled over.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12 (Magic is Might)*</sup></sub>

She may have used one to unlock a door moments before her confirmed non-verbal spell, but this instance is less clear.

> “She pointed her wand at the padlocked and heavily graffitied fire door beside them, which burst open with a crash.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 12 (Magic is Might)*</sup></sub>

She also cast what's later identified as a Stinging Jinx and she seems to use it non-verbally as no incantation is mentioned.

> “He saw Hermione point her wand, not towards the outside, but into his face; there was a bang, a burst of white light, and he buckled in agony, unable to see. He could feel his face swelling rapidly under his hands, as heavy footfalls surrounded him.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 23 (Malfoy Manor)*</sup></sub>

She used another spell with seemingly no incantation to conjure flowers for Harry to put on his parents' graves.

> “But Hermione raised her wand, moved it in a circle through the air and a wreath of Christmas roses blossomed before them. Harry caught it and laid it on his parents’ grave.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 16 (Godric's Hollow)*</sup></sub>

In addition, she may have used a non-verbal spell to attempt to save Lavender Brown from Fenrir Greyback.

> “NO!’ shrieked Hermione, and with a deafening blast from her wand Fenrir Greyback was thrown backwards from the feebly stirring body of Lavender Brown.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 32 (The Elder Wand)*</sup></sub>

**Ron seems to cast a Stunning Spell non-verbally.**

Ron casts a spell where no incantation is mentioned, and the man he cast it on is later referred to as Stunned. It seems to imply that he cast it non-verbally, but it's not explicit.

> “The man lunged at her, reaching for her throat: then, with a bang and a burst of red light he was thrown backwards on to the ground, unconscious. Ron stood there, his wand still outstretched and a look of shock visible behind his beard.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 26 (Gringotts)*</sup></sub>

**Harry cast Levicorpus in Half-Blood Prince but no confirmed non-verbal spells after.**

Harry was able to successfully cast Levicorpus, a spell in the Half-Blood Prince's potion book intended for non-verbal use, non-verbally.

> “Pointing his wand at nothing in particular, he gave it an upward flick and said Levicorpus! inside his head.
>
> ‘Aaaaaaaargh!’
>
> There was a flash of light and the room was full of voices: everyone had woken up as Ron had let out a yell.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 12 (Silver and Opals)*</sup></sub>

He was also able to cast the counter-jinx, Liberacorpus, non-verbally as well.

> “He groped for the potion book and riffled through it in a panic, trying to find the right page; at last he located it and deciphered one cramped word underneath the spell: praying that this was the counter-jinx, Harry thought Liberacorpus! with all his might. There was another flash of light and Ron fell in a heap on to his mattress.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 12 (Silver and Opals)*</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm pretty sure Harry did master non-verbal spells eventually. I can't imagine an Auror not being able to do that.

Comment: Harry cast a non-verbal Refilling Charm in the scene with Hagrid and Slughorn in Hagrid's hut towards the end of Half-Blood Prince, albeit with an active dose of lucky potion potentially helping.

Answer (score 0):

In *The Deathly Hallows*, Harry casts multiple stunning spells silently before shouting "Protego" and throwing off the cloak

Comment: This answer could be improved greatly if you added in some quotes from the book